# Scientific publication discussion community or public peer reviewing

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm curious if there is a community<sup>1</sup>, on this network, where scientific publications can be discussed? Or to stick more to the Q&A philosophy, where questions about publications are answered?

I've seen a lot of publications that were unclear to me and after some re-reading and asking other people it turned out to be super simple and that I was just stupid. But as often it turned out that the publication made false assumptions, were missing important information or, the worst, made up results. For the last point I want to point to the last 3 min of [this nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLlA1w4OZWQ) and the corresponding [blog entry](http://blog.chembark.com/2013/08/14/some-very-suspicious-tem-images-in-nano-letters/).

I've searched for something like this, but wasn't able to find anything. Is there such a community And if not, maybe an alternative site?

I can imagine that it maybe will not work out so good, because there are so many publications out there and it's hard to find anybody else who's familiar with the one I've problem with. But I think it is possible. Any most likely you're not the first or only one you has problems with some cryptic formula. This also could help authors to improve their future work to see what parts were unclear.

<sub>I'm not sure how to call it exactly so I choose Community for now</sub>

Comment: Is this related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210878/replacing-scientific-journals-with-se

Comment: [Here's an example](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/726/322) of a question that concerned a specific scientific publication on the Data Science site.

Comment: @rene: Yes, wish I had found this before. airthomas: Nice example.

Comment: It is not part of the SE network, and differs from it in several important ways, but [Physics Overflow](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/) has a [paper reviews section](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/activity/refereeing).

Comment: Another platform you may be interested in (quite different to the SE model) is [PubPeer](http://pubpeer.com).

Comment: Yet another platform: arXiv Analytics, at http://arxitics.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A specific question about a part of a scientific paper is likely on-topic on all of the science sites in the SE network.

Discussions are pretty much off-topic by design on most SE sites. But asking about particular aspects of a published paper don't have to lead to a discussion and can be perfectly valid questions for an SE site.

You should be somewhat careful in setting up the question, and make it relatively easy for the viewers to see what it is about. Anyone seriously answering will likely read the paper anyway, but making it obvious what the question is without requiring users to read the paper is still important. You'll have to keep fair use in mind here, distilling the essential parts from the paper into your question is crucial.

What is not on-topic on any SE site are broad reviews of papers, or discussions like "what do you think about this paper?".

Comment: Yes, I though of that and @airthomas gave a good example of this. Thanks